# Using an old iPhone 4s to connect to internet to develop apps

Tags: wifi, ios, iphone

I have an old iphone 4s but just upgraded to a new iphone 6 and switched cellular service from the 4s to the 6.  Wifi broke for some reason a long time ago on the 4s (the buttons are permanetly disabled).

Is there anyway to connect to the internet? I have my phone plugged into a wifi enabled macbook but phone still has no internet connection.

Comment: Does your carrier allow Personal Hotspot? If so, try connecting your iPhone 4s to your iPhone 6 via Personal Hotspot. If it doesn't work, then it's possible that your iPhone can no longer connect to the Internet. Also, what do you mean "the buttons are permanently disabled"? Do you mean the physical ones (volume buttons) or something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: The wifi button on the general -> settings is permanetly grayed out and the one on the pop up menu is too when you slide from the bottom of the screen to the top.  Is there a physcial way to turn wifi on and off outside of the software buttons in ios?

Comment: what i need is reverse tethering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your iPhone 4s running (at least) iOS 7.1? If so, then I believe this support page from Apple should do the trick:

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/ts1559

If neither of Apple's instructions work, then one idea is to you back up your iPhone using iTunes and restore the device. I recommend making a clean restore. If the Wi-Fi works, then you can either leave it as it is or go ahead and restore again, but this time, using the backup that you made on iTunes.

If that still doesn't work, then... well, I don't usually recommend this, but you could jailbreak the iPhone and try a fix from there. I'm not entirely familiar with that process, but that's the only other thing that I can possibly suggest. Otherwise, you're out of luck (unless you want to try the Apple Store to get it fixed/replaced, but I think that it'd be a waste of your time).

Comment: Cool thanks i'll test this all out now. Yeah its running ios 7.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the hot spot over Bluetooth, no wifi needed.